# Android: Change menu divider left right margin

Tags: android, android-styles

I'd like to change the menu divider left right margin

The original screenshot is like this

[image]

But I want to change to this

[image]

Currently, my style.xml is

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
</style>

<!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Divider Property -->
<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    <!-- I put this line dividerPadding, but it doesn't work-->
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">10px</item> 
</style>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks.
Eric

Comment: How to use this style?

Answer (score 4):

I found Sukhwant Singh Grewal's answer useful (hence upvoted) but a bit concise. Here's a more fully spelled-out solution.

In styles.xml I added the line:

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/divider</item>
```

Then I added the following divider.xml file under res/drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/divider_line"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

Lastly, I added the following divider_line.xml file under res/drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/pink_dark"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="3dp"/>

</shape>
```

This seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**under res/drawable**
add divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
    android:left="60dp"
    android:right="10dp" android:drawable="@drawable/divider">


</item>
</layer-list>
```

in `android:drawable="@drawable/divider_image"`you can use any color like `android:drawable="@color/black"`. Then take it as background of your divider and give height.